# Multiplication of two 64 digit number_Gettin Input Mismatch Exception

Tags: java, algorithm, exception, multiplication, inputmismatchexception

```
public class Karatsubamultiplication {

    public static void multiply(long ac , long ad, long bc, long bd, long digits)
    
    {
      double mul=0;
      
      mul = Math.pow(10, digits) *ac + Math.pow(10, digits/2)*(ad+bc)+bd;
      
      System.out.println("The multiplication answer is "+mul);
    }
    
    public static long[] splitnum(long n1) {
        long[] split= new long[3];
        long divider=1;
        long num =0;
        long counter=0;
        num=n1;
        while(num>0) {
            num=num/10;
            counter=counter+1;
        }
        split[2]=counter;
        for(long i=0;i<counter/2;i++) {
            divider*=10;
        }       
        split[0]=n1/divider;
        split[1]=n1%divider;
                
        return split;       
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);    
        System.out.println("Enter value of n1 and n2 ");
        long n1 = sc.nextLong();
        long n2 = sc.nextLong();
        long ac=0,ad=0,bc=0,bd=0,digits=0;
        if(n1/10==0 && n2/10==0)
        {
            System.out.println("The multiplication answer is "+n1*n2);
        }
        else
        {
            long[] a= splitnum(n1);
            long[] c =splitnum(n2);     
            ac = a[0]*c[0];
            ad = a[0]*c[1];
            bc= a[1]*c[0];
            bd= a[1]*c[1];
            digits=a[2];
            multiply(ac,ad,bc,bd,digits);
            
        }
                                
    }       
}
```

Multiplication of two 64 digit number_Gettin Input Mismatch Exception

Query : when i give 2 64 bit number result will be in 128 bits. Getting Input Mismatch exception:(

Need help to enhance this code in order to handle this exception .>

Answer (score 1):

`InputMismatchException` is thrown by the `nextLong()` method, when the input entered by the user is not, in fact, a long.

The way you've used scanner means that `nextLong` is looking for a space, enter (newline), end of the stream, or other whitespace, and will then parse all the character that precede it as a long. Note that this means the input must consist of an optional `+` or `-`, and then a bunch of digits, and that is all, and that the number must fit between -2^63 and +2^63-1 (so, between `-9223372036854775808` and `+9223372036854775807`). Any number below/above that isn't a long and therefore causes that exception.

Fix: Well, you tell me. What do you want this program to do? Any numbers outside of that range **do not fit into the long datatype** in the first place.

If you don't need your program to deal with numbers that extreme, then.. don't enter them.

If you do, then this code needs to be replaced entirely; don't call .nextLong() at all. Presumably, just call `.next()` and use `java.math.BigInteger` instead of longs, which can take numbers of any size.